# Pygame black screen crash

Tags: python, pygame

I don't what happened, it was working few minutes ago, but now it's not. It's crashing every time.

```
import pygame, sys

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 700
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Qix")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Player Class
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)
        self.color = (250, 120, 60)
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.up_pressed = False
        self.down_pressed = False
        self.speed = 4
        self.enterPush = False
        while self.enterPush is True:
            if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
                self.velX = -self.speed
            if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
                self.velX = self.speed

            self.x += self.velX
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.x), int(self.y), 32, 32)


    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)


    def push(self):
        if self.rect.x>760 or self.rect.y>560:

            self.enterPush = True


    def update(self):
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        while self.enterPush is False:
            if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
                self.velX = -self.speed
            if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
                self.velX = self.speed
            if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed :
                self.velY = -self.speed
            if self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed :
                self.velY = self.speed

            self.x += self.velX
            self.y += self.velY

            self.rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.x), int(self.y), 32, 32)




player = Player(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = False


    win.fill((12, 24, 36))
    player.draw(win)
    player.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have to fix this in one hour.
I read other answers related to this but nothing seems to work.
Just adding details
Just adding details Just adding details
Just adding details
Just adding details
Just adding details

Comment: what is the error? also You should provide [MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `player.update()` this causes the "crash" because it cannot exit the loop

Comment: You have not added detail. Don't bypass the system. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go, fixed the code:

```py
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 700
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Qix")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Player Class
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)
        self.color = (250, 120, 60)
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.up_pressed = False
        self.down_pressed = False
        self.speed = 4
        self.enterPush = False
        while self.enterPush is True:
            if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
                self.velX = -self.speed
            if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
                self.velX = self.speed

            self.x += self.velX
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.x), int(self.y), 32, 32)

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

    def push(self):
        if self.rect.x>760 or self.rect.y>560:

            self.enterPush = True

    def update(self):
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        # while self.enterPush is False:
        if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
            self.velX = -self.speed
        if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
            self.velX = self.speed
        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed :
            self.velY = -self.speed
        if self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed :
            self.velY = self.speed

        self.x += self.velX
        self.y += self.velY

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.x), int(self.y), 32, 32)


player = Player(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = False

    win.fill((12, 24, 36))
    player.draw(win)
    player.update()
    # pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

First of about formatting (suggestion according to PEP 8): 1 newline between class method definitions, import like in the code I edited (tho this is acceptable: `from module import class, func, etc`).

Also I don't see the point of both `.flip()` and `.update()` since they basically do the same.

About Your poblem:

```py
while self.enterPush is False:
            if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
                self.velX = -self.speed
            if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
                self.velX = self.speed
            if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed :
                self.velY = -self.speed
            if self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed :
                self.velY = self.speed

            self.x += self.velX
            self.y += self.velY

            self.rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.x), int(self.y), 32, 32)
```

this was Your issue: the while loop

solution: not using it:

```py
def update(self):
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        # while self.enterPush is False:
        if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
            self.velX = -self.speed
        if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
            self.velX = self.speed
        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed :
            self.velY = -self.speed
        if self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed :
            self.velY = self.speed

        self.x += self.velX
        self.y += self.velY

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.x), int(self.y), 32, 32)
```